# Show a map from $(c_0)^*$ to $\ell^1$ is an isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, isometry

So, for a bit of context, i'm trying to show that $(c_0)^* = \ell^1$.

Given $b = (b_i)_{i=0}^\infty \in \ell^1$, define $f$ in $(c_0)^*$ by

$f_b((a_i)_{i=0}^\infty) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ib_i$.

Then I have $\vert f_b(a)\vert \leq \vert \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ib_i\vert \leq max_i \vert a_i \vert\Vert b_i\Vert_1. $

So that gives me $\Vert f_b \Vert \leq \Vert b \Vert_1 $

To show that I have an isometry, I just have to show the other direction, but i'm struggling to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: define a sequence $(x_n)$ in $c_0$ by putting $x_n^{(i)}=\text{sgn}(b_i)$ if $i\le n$ and $x_n^{(i)}=0$ if $i>n$. Calculate $|f_b(x_n)|$ and look what happens if you let $n$ tend to infinity.

Comment: so I get
$\vert f_b(x_n) \vert = \vert \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \vert = \sum_{i=1}^n \vert b_i \vert \rightarrow \Vert b \Vert _1$ as $ n \rightarrow \infty $, right?

Comment: @user142671 Almost, you should leave out $|\sum_{i=1}^n b_i|$ since the $b_i$ can differ in sign.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: do first the case when $b$ has only two nonzero components.
**Try to understand when the inequality becomes an equality.**

Then you should be able to do the case when only a finite number of components of $b$ are nonzero.

For the general case, remember that it suffices to obtain

$$\sup_{\|a\|_\infty= 1}\sum a_ib_i=\|b\|_1$$

(nobody tells you that the $\sup$ is really achieved!)

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand what you're getting at... I feel like it should be obvious!

Comment: Have you managed to do the case of two components?

Comment: No I haven't... I should probably look back at it in the morning :P

Comment: My advice is the hint typeset in bold: you have written an inequality. Now you just have to understand when it is an equality

Comment: ok, when $\vert a_ib_i \vert = a_ib_i$? You've just used the definition of $\Vert f_b \Vert$ i think...